# Automating thumbnail generation on high traffic

Tags: zend-framework, automation, thumbnails, gearman

I'm building a Zend Framework application which uses a lot of photos in different sizes (thumbnails).

I plan to generate the thumbnails asynchronously:

1. user uploads the photo
2. the server generates thumbnails in all sizes (eg. using gearman worker)
3. all the images are uploaded to the Amazon S3.

Is there any good tool for generating thumbnails (resizing, cropping, sharpening) on the server, or PHP + GD will be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recomend [phpthumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/). I use it, and I have no complains so far.

Comment: Indeed. In that case, you don't even need to do it asynchronously. The first call for the thumb invokes all the resizing processing and server-side caching handles it after that. Of course, initiating that initial resizing process on upload means that even that first public request is as fast as all the subsequent ones.

Comment: Is there any way to tie the thumbnail cache with some storage adapter, e.g. AWS?